# How to find the max value of val1 where val2 is the maximum?

Tags: sql, sybase

Sybase DBMS

In my players table, I have 4 columns:

1. player
2. score
3. post_dt
4. add_dt

If I want to find the score of the player where post_dt is the maximum value, and the add_dt is the maximum value of that post_dt and that player, how do I do this?  My below query takes a super long time to run and probably not very efficient.

```
select player, score from tb t1 
where post_dt in 
      (select max(add_dt) 
       from tb t2 
       where t1.player = t2.player and t2.post_dt in 
             (select max(post_dt) 
              from tb t2 
              where t1.player = t2.player))
```

Table

```
PLAYER    SCORE POST_DT      ADD_DT 

001         15  2017-02-01   2017-01-15
001         26  2017-02-01   2017-01-17  
001         31  2017-01-28   2017-01-10
002         4   2017-03-25   2017-02-25  
002         14  2017-03-25   2017-02-13
002         27  2017-03-25   2017-03-05
003         31  2017-01-02   2016-12-25
003         4   2017-01-03   2016-12-25
```

Intended results from query:

```
01, 26, 2017-02-01, 2017-01-17
02, 27, 2017-03-25, 2017-03-05
03,  4, 2017-01-03, 2016-12-25
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Can you elaborate it a bit, preferably with some sample data. It is hard to understand your requirement.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?) and version? in addition to Cetin's comment, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then come back and update your question

Comment: I updated my post with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using correlated subqueries.

```
SELECT t1.player,
       t1.score
       FROM tb t1
       WHERE t1.post_dt = (SELECT max(t2.post_dt)
                                  FROM tb t2
                                  WHERE t2.player = t1.player)
             AND t1.add_dt = (SELECT max(t2.add_dt)
                                     FROM tb t2
                                     WHERE t2.player = t1.player
                                           AND t2.post_dt = t1.post_dt);
```

Or, if your DBMS supports window functions, using the `rank()` window function.

```
SELECT x.player,
       x.score
       FROM (SELECT t.player,
                    t.score,
                    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY t.player
                                 ORDER BY t.post_dt DESC,
                                          t.add_dt DESC) r
                    FROM tb t) x
       WHERE x.r = 1;
```

Yet another option is inner joining subqueries, that build the maxima by `player` or `player` and `post_dt`, respectively.

```
SELECT t1.player,
       t1.score
       FROM tb t1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.player,
                               max(t2.post_dt) post_dt
                               FROM tb t2
                               GROUP BY t2.player) t3
                       ON t3.player = t1.player
                          AND t3.post_dt = t1.post_dt
            INNER JOIN (SELECT t3.player,
                               t3.post_dt,
                               max(t3.add_dt) add_dt
                               FROM tb t3
                               GROUP BY t3.player,
                                        t3.post_dt) t4
                       ON t4.player = t1.player
                          AND t4.post_dt = t1.post_dt
                          AND t4.add_dt = t1.add_dt;
```

Comment: This is great!  Thank you.  I used your second solution.